# Group MySQL query results by date and each group has header and own div

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I feel like I may be over-thinking this solution... so I figured I'd get some additional advice. I want to query my database for a list of 'events' and group events that have the same date under a single header in addition, I want this 'group' in it's own container. I've figured out the single header issue browsing other questions, but the container is giving me grief!

**For Example:**

**This:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='event-image.jpg'>
    <h1>October 15th, 2012</h1>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <img src='event-image.jpg'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
```

**Not This:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='event-image.jpg'>
    <h1>October 15th, 2012</h1>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <img src='event-image.jpg'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Event Name</h3>
    <p>Details</p>
</div>
```

**This:**

```
October 15, 2012
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3
```

**Not This:**

```
October 15, 2012
Event 1
October 15, 2012
Event 2
October 15, 2012
Event 3
```

**MySQL Query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %D, %Y') AS postdate, time, venue, cost, city,   spotlight, image
        FROM shows WHERE date >= $curDate
        ORDER BY date ASC, spotlight DESC LIMIT $startRow," . SHOWMAX;
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<?php 
    $prevDate = null;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="content">
        <?php 
        if (!empty($row['image'])) { ?>
            <img src="/images/thumbs/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>">
        <?php 
        }

        if ($row['postdate'] != $prevDate) { ?>
            <h1><?php echo $row['postdate']; ?></h1>
            <?php $prevDate = $row['postdate'];
        } ?>
        <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>   
        <p><?php echo $row['venue'] . " | " . $row['city'] . " | " . $row['time'] . " | " .  $row['cost']; ?></p>
        </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Results:**

```
<div class="content">
<img src="/images/thumbs/defining-times-news-00.jpg">
    <h1>October 13th, 2012</h1>
    <h3>Relient K w/ Hellogoodby, William Beckett & House of Heroes</h3>    
    <p>Cain's Ballroom | Tulsa, OK | 9:00 | $10</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
<div class="content">
    <h3>Rod Steward & Stevie Nicks</h3> 
    <p>BOK Center | Tulsa, OK | 9:00 | $45</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
<div class="content">
    <h3>Gary Allan</h3> 
    <p>Hard Rock Hotel & Casino | Tulsa, OK | 9:00 | $30</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
<div class="content">
    <img src="/images/thumbs/dead-sea-choir-news-00.jpg">
    <h1>October 14th, 2012</h1>
    <h3>Nalani Proctor and Kierston White</h3>  
    <p>Bluebonnet | Norman, OK | 9:00 | $5</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
<div class="content">
    <h3>Bungalouski</h3>    
    <p>Bluebonnet | Norman, OK | 9:00 | FREE</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
    <h3>Relient K w/ Hellogoodby, William Beckett & House of Heroes</h3>    
    <p>Cain's Ballroom | Tulsa, OK | 9:00 | $10</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
```

I hope this isn't too convoluted! Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is it doing wrong? Is it the horizontal-line? Your example didn't mention items with `class="content"` so I can't tell if that is right or not.

Comment: I thought my example did... but what it is doing wrong is wrapping each 'event' (H3 tag and P tag) in <div class="content"> followed by the horizontal rule... I would like it to wrap all 'events' with the same date and then followed by a horizontal line to add visual separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$prevDate = null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mark = false;
    if ($row['postdate'] != $prevDate) {
        $mark = true;
        $prevDate = $row['postdate'];
    }
    ?>
    <? if ($mark) { ?>
        <div class="content">
        <? } ?>
        <? if (!empty($row['image'])) { ?>
            <img src="/images/thumbs/<?= $row['image'] ?>">
        <? } ?>

        <? if ($mark) { ?>
            <h1><?= $row['postdate']; ?></h1>
        <? } ?>
        <h3><?= $row['title']; ?></h3>   
        <p><?= $row['venue'] . " | " . $row['city'] . " | " . $row['time'] . " | " . $row['cost']; ?></p>
        <? if ($mark) { ?>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
    <? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: This is much closer! ...and I think I might be able to work it out now.

Comment: Please, see an example [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xoSFOi). It does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working thanks to 'khomyakoshka' for leading me in the right direction!

...now I'm not saying this is the best way to do it, but it works!

```
<?php   
$prevDate = null;
$i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $mark = false;
        if ($row['postdate'] != $prevDate) {
            $mark = true;
            $prevDate = $row['postdate'];
        }

        if ($mark && $i == 0) {
?>
            <div class="content">
<?php
        } elseif ($mark) {
?>          
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
            <div class="content">
<?php           
        }

        if (!empty($row['image'])) { 
?>
            <img src="/images/thumbs/<?= $row['image'] ?>">
<?php
        }

        if ($mark) { ?>
            <h1><?php echo $row['postdate']; ?></h1>
<?php
        }
?>
        <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>   
        <p><?php echo $row['venue'] . " | " . $row['city'] . " | " . $row['time'] . " | " . $row['cost']; ?></p>
<?php
                $i++;
                }
            ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since you did answer the question, I just needed to modify it a bit to fit my code. Thanks again! I'll be using this place more often.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow =)